# Help define referential integrity in Zend Framework 1.8.3 using Data Mapper model

Tags: zend-framework, referential-integrity

I am unable to define referential integrity relationship using Zend Frameworks table relationships as documented in the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html).

I have exhausted every possible configuration (so it seems), and now am facing the prospect of developing the application without being able to use cascading deletions, which  is undesirable.

Can anyone see what is wrong or offer any suggestions?

My project is setup using the new ZF 1.8.3 recommended method, with datamappers, and I wonder if this is a reason why I am unable to replicate the behavior as described in the reference guide. Does anyone have any experience of this problem?

Here are the relevant parts of the classes:

application/models/UsersMapper.php

```
class Default_Model_UsersMapper {
    public function deleteUser($id, Default_Model_Users $users){

    $usersTable = new Default_Model_DbTable_Users();        
    $usersRowset = $usersTable->find( $id );    
    $userToDelete = $usersRowset->current();    
    $userToDelete->delete();

}
```

application/models/DbTable/Users.php

```
class Default_Model_DbTable_Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
/**
 * @var string Name of the database table
 */
protected $_name = 'users';

/**
 * @desc  reference map 
 * 
 */
 protected $_referenceMap = array(
    'Comment' => array(
    'columns'       =>  array('user_id'),
        'refTableClass' =>  'Comment',
        'refColumns'    =>  array('id'),
        'onDelete'      =>  self::CASCADE
    )
);

}
```

application/models/CommentMapper.php

… and the related table defined by the class:

Comment.php

```
class Default_Model_DbTable_Comment extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
/**
 * @var string Name of the database table
 */
protected $_name = 'comment';

    /**
 * @desc Defining referential integrity here since we are using MyISAM
 * Dependent tables are referred via the class name. 
 */
protected $_dependentTables = array('Users');
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an unused second parameter to deleteUser()? 

Default_Model_Users $users

Comment: This is kind of stupid... And what about class autoload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhhh, I see it now. Your classes are named Default_Model_DbTable_Xxx, yet you refer to them as Xxx in your classes. Do the changes tharkun suggested and change your classnames to be valid:

e.g.

```
protected $_dependentTables = array('Comment');
```

and

```
'refTableClass' =>      'User',
```

becomes

```
protected $_dependentTables = array('Default_Model_DbTable_Comment');
```

and

```
'refTableClass' => 'Default_Model_DbTable_User'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for spotting the mistake in the class definitions.

My problem getting Zend Framework to provide a DRI layer has become narrowed and can now be summarized as such.

Using these class definitions I am able to delete the user but not the related comment through my local UserController  "public/users/delete/userId/22"

```
    class Default_Model_DbTable_Comment extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
    {
        /**
         * @var string Name of the database table
         */
        protected $_name = 'comment';

        /**
         * @desc  reference map 
         * 
         * Rows in the comment table are to be automatically deleted if the row in the 
     * User table to which they refer is deleted
     *    
     */
     protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'User' => array(
            'columns'       => 'user_id',   // the foreign key(s)
            'refTableClass' => 'Default_Model_DbTable_Users',
            'refColumns'    =>  'id',
            'onDelete'      =>  self::CASCADE,
        )
    );

}
class Default_Model_DbTable_Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    /**
     * @var string Name of the database table
     */
    protected $_name = 'users';


     /**
     * @desc Defining referential integrity here since we are using MyISAM
     * Dependent tables are referred via the class name. 
     */
    protected $_dependentTables = 'Default_Model_DbTable_Comment';



}
```